# python result shows diffrenece things than what i expected

Tags: python

I have written this code, but the result returns `no such  file exists`, even though all the files exist.

```
def shomaresh_tedad_kalamat(esme_file):
    try:
        with open(esme_file) as f:
            mohtaviat=f.read()
    except:
           print("no such a file exists") 
           pass
    else:
           kalamat=mohtaviat.split()
           tedad_kalamat=len(kalamat)
           print(esme_file , tedad_kalamat ," kalame darad")  
esme_file=['data1.txt','data2w.txt','data3w.txt','a.txt']
for esm in  esme_file:   
  shomaresh_tedad_kalamat(esme_file)
```

Can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: If the files are not in the same directory as the python script you'll probably get this error. Better idea is to specify the file full path.

Comment: remove the try/except/else so that you can see what the actual error is... And fix the indentation of the snippet.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to put esme_file as 'esme_file' and add the file type to the end ex. .txt, .csv, etc.

Comment: you are calling the function with the list of files instead of each file. change to `shomaresh_tedad_kalamat(esm)`. Also the point of using `with` is to avoid the use of `try/except`...

Comment: @Tomerikoo, the use of `with` context manager is to remove the need to close the file, not to avoid try/except

Comment: @buran you are right, my comment is a bit misleading. I meant that the `with` handles exceptions for you and closes the file. Of course if you wish to catch those exceptions and handle them it's perfectly fine. Thanks for the correction

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def shomaresh_tedad_kalamat(esme_file):
try:
    for i in esme_file:
        with open(i) as f:
            mohtaviat=f.read()
except:
       print("no such a file exists")
       pass
else:
       kalamat=mohtaviat.split()
       tedad_kalamat=len(kalamat)
       f.close()
       print(esme_file , tedad_kalamat ," kalame darad")
```

You are trying to pass a list into your function and then you want to open a full list like:

```
with(['/home/wess/tmp/data1.txt','/home/wess/tmp/data2.txt','/home/wess/tmp/data3.txt',])
```

it's wrong.
Create a loop and pass every element in the function `with`.